# Labeled text box

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i am trying to write a control template where i want a label for text box on top of the textbox. So i invite your suggestions for how to achieve this.

so far i did that using a stack pannel with vertical orientation and then added textblock and text box. Like wise i created 45 stackpannels. So i dont want to go like that. instaed i want to write a control template where i can have label and text box and then set label value and text box value.

my:CustomControl labelText="First Name:" TextBoxText="john Doe" />
any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a UserControl with DependencyProperties for Text and Label, put your StackPanel in it, and bind the label and textbox to the dependency properties.

Make sure the `Text` property has `FrameworkPropertyMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault`

Comment: actually i am new to implementation... can you put some sample code to override the dependancy proprties..

Comment: Type `propdp` and press `Tab`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

It includes both HeaderedContentControl and DataField controls. The DataField is mainly for use with DataForm, but as far as I know, you can use it any way you like. The HeaderedContentControl I haven't tried myself, but it could be just what you are looking for.